# How to import modules installed with --user option?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, pip, mysql-connector

I've successfully installed a package `mysql.connector` as a user with pip:

```
$ pip --user install mysql-connector
Successfully installed mysql-connector-2.2.9
```

I can see it in my ~/.local directory:

```
$ find . -name mysql -print
./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql
./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysqlx/protobuf/(lots of stuff)
```

I have added this directory to my PATH

```
$ echo $PATH
...:/home/picasso/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/
```

Yet, when I try to import, error

```
$ python3
>>> import mysql
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
```

How do I specify where python should look for said library file?

In C++, I might add an include directory. Ty Keith :^)

Comment: The PATH variable is for your shell to know where to find executables. You need to add your local site packages to your PYTHONPATH environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

So, I figured it out about 30000ms after posting this question.

For posterity, set the PYTHONPATH variable, like so

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

*sigh*

Comment: downvote please explain. I took the time to document the answer to my own question for the benefit of others. ;(